# Connectivity problems migrating from 1.5.3 to 2.0

Tags: orleans

I am in the process of updating an Orleans 1.5.3 application to 2.0 but the updated version fails to start properly with all silos in the cluster reporting that they cannot ping the other live nodes. I am able to deploy the 1.5.3 version to the same cloud service & virtual network with no problems so I do not believe this is a network issue.

```
07-02-2018 22:09:51 EventId="101021" Message="Exception getting a sending socket to endpoint S172.0.0.4:11111:268290539" Exception="System.TimeoutException: Connection to 172.0.0.4:11111 could not be established in 00:00:05
  at Orleans.Runtime.SocketManager.Connect(Socket s, IPEndPoint endPoint, TimeSpan connectionTimeout) in D:\build\agent\_work\18\s\src\Orleans.Core\Messaging\SocketManager.cs:line 206
  at Orleans.Runtime.SocketManager.SendingSocketCreator(IPEndPoint target) in D:\build\agent\_work\18\s\src\Orleans.Core\Messaging\SocketManager.cs:line 108
  at Orleans.Runtime.LRU`2.Get(TKey key) in D:\build\agent\_work\18\s\src\Orleans.Core\Utils\LRU.cs:line 160
  at Orleans.Runtime.Messaging.SiloMessageSender.GetSendingSocket(Message msg, Socket& socket, SiloAddress& targetSilo, String& error) in D:\build\agent\_work\18\s\src\Orleans.Runtime\Messaging\SiloMessageSender.cs:line 85"
07-02-2018 22:09:33 EventId="100661" Message="-Failed to get ping responses from all 2 silos that are currently listed as Active in the Membership table. Newly joining silos validate connectivity with all pre-existing silos that are listed as Active in the table and have written I Am Alive in the table in the last 00:10:00 period, before they are allowed to join the cluster. Active silos are: [[SiloAddress=S172.0.0.4:11111:268290539 SiloName=ModelEngine.Silo.GraphBuilder_IN_0 Status=Active HostName=RD0003FFA5B97C ProxyPort=30000 RoleName=Orleans.Runtime UpdateZone=0 FaultZone=0 StartTime = 2018-07-03 05:08:59.428 GMT IAmAliveTime = 2018-07-03 05:09:09.537 GMT  ], [SiloAddress=S172.0.0.5:11111:268290516 SiloName=ModelEngine.Silo.GraphBuilder_IN_1 Status=Active HostName=RD0003FFA5ADDE ProxyPort=30000 RoleName=Orleans.Runtime UpdateZone=0 FaultZone=0 StartTime = 2018-07-03 05:08:36.901 GMT IAmAliveTime = 2018-07-03 05:08:47.168 GMT  ]]" Exception=""
```

Looking at the membership table, everything looks consistent between the 1.5.3 and the 2.0 nodes with the exception of the RoleName column. For the 2.0 nodes, this column always contains "Orleans.Runtime" rather than the role name. Not sure if this is related but it is the only differnce I can find.

Comment: Which particular version are you running, @jafletch? Is it 2.0.0 or 2.0.3?
How are you configuring the silo and the client?

Comment: I just started the update process yesterday and pulled everything current so 2.0.3. I converted all of the legacy configuration to the new style. Thus far, I am just trying to get the silo cluster to start so no client is involved yet.

Comment: Are you able to show your configuration? Is 172.0.0.4 an IP which is accessible from the other silos?